# How to access underlying navigation stack of mvvm light

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I know Xamarin.form's underlying navigation stack can be accessed.

Using the following API

```
Var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;

Var firstPageToRemove = navigation.NavigationStack[2];
```

But how can I access underlying navigationstack of MVVM
Because INavigationService provides very less API to manipulate the navigation stack

[image]

Comment: You will have to create an own interface and implement it for the various platforms. This question has a similar solution as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243754/how-do-i-implement-our-very-own-navigation-service-in-mvvmlight