# How to implement custom navigation service in mvvmlight

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light

I am not quite comfortable with the existing MVVMlight navigation interface methods and that is very minimal and I want to implement my very own navigational interface in which I can expose sophisticated methods that manipulates the navigational stack  and integrate it with the MVVM light.

Any guidance on achieving this is very much appreciated

Update:

I would like to implement other transitions for movement between pages like page curl,flip,rotate etc

Comment: How do you mean `integrate it with the MVVM light`? You can just create your own `ICustomNavigationService` interface, implement it for the various OS's, and then register the implementation in the `SimpleIoc` container. If you are not that familiar how navigation is done in the different platforms you can look at the source code here https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and see how it is done by the author of `MVVM light`

Comment: Thanks for providing light on this ! Basically I have an app which already uses INavigationService which is in the shared code..its used by iOS,Android and windows app..now I just want to replace the iNavigation service with my own service which will have extra APIs providing access to the navigational stack .. is it possible if so how to do that ?

Comment: You create a new interface, lets call it `ISharathNavigationService`, and define all needed operations. You use this interface in your shared code. Then you implement it on each platform; (`WindowsNavigationService` or similar) and register the implementation to the interface with the `SimpleIoc` container (like  `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISharathNavigationService, WindowsNavigationService>()`). Finally in your shared code you call the `SimpleIoc` container for the instance of the `ISharathNavigationService` (similar to `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ISharathNavigationService>()`)

Comment: Thanks,Basically I want to create an interface where I will have access to my own navigation stack and I can provide access to the underlying navigational stack via Methods.If you could explain me how to do that its very much appreciated ! Showing an example or model would be very good

Comment: I would like to customize the transition of page push and pop too

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? Where are you stuck exactly? I know its a little work; I'd tackle this problem by looking at the source code from mvvm light to understand how navigation is done by the "pros", and then trying to implement it by myself by adding the stuff I additionally need. I'm sure there are already good resources for both iOS and Android how to modify the navigation stack

Comment: I am navigating basically from this particular page... page_middle and pushing 4 pages one by one not in a single time based on user choice ...then I want to pop all four pages in one time but to achieve that I am calling four times go back and it looks awkward in UI transition point of view... If Call navigateTo(page_middle) then it creates one more instance of page_middle....so I am thinking to access the navigationstack which is a array and remove the last 4 pages one by one in array ...and leave the navigation stack with the page_middle as top item  so it won't look bad in ui transition

Comment: if possible I want to show a transition of the push while removing the 4 pages and leaving it with page_middle

Comment: I'd just recommend you start coding, it sounds like you know what you want to archive, and it sounds doable. I think you have enough to get started (for example the existing code from `MVVM light`).

Comment: I am wondering if its possible .. I will start anyhow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full implementation example that would solve the problem by adding a new interface that fully replaces the one from MvvmLight and also allows you to choose whether to use animations or not. In this example, we add the ability to control whether the navigation should be animated or not:

**Interface**

```
public interface ICustomNavigationService
{
    string CurrentPageKey { get; }
    void GoBack(bool animate = true);
    void NavigateTo(string pageKey, bool animate = true);
    void NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter, bool animate = true);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class NavigationService : ICustomNavigationService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _pagesByKey = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    private NavigationPage _navigation;
    public NavigationPage Navigation
    {
        get
        {
            return _navigation;
        }
    }
    public string CurrentPageKey
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_pagesByKey)
            {
                if (_navigation.CurrentPage == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var pageType = _navigation.CurrentPage.GetType();

                return _pagesByKey.ContainsValue(pageType)
                    ? _pagesByKey.First(p => p.Value == pageType).Key
                    : null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GoBack(bool animate = true)
    {
        _navigation.PopAsync(animate);
        MessagingCenter.Send<INavigationService>(this, "NAVIGATING");
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string pageKey, bool animate = true)
    {
        NavigateTo(pageKey, null, animate);
        MessagingCenter.Send<INavigationService>(this, "NAVIGATING");
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter, bool animate = true)
    {
        lock (_pagesByKey)
        {
            if (_pagesByKey.ContainsKey(pageKey))
            {
                var type = _pagesByKey[pageKey];
                ConstructorInfo constructor;
                object[] parameters;

                if (parameter == null)
                {
                    constructor = type.GetTypeInfo()
                        .DeclaredConstructors
                        .FirstOrDefault(c => !c.GetParameters().Any());

                    parameters = new object[]
                    {
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    constructor = type.GetTypeInfo()
                        .DeclaredConstructors
                        .FirstOrDefault(
                            c =>
                            {
                                var p = c.GetParameters();
                                return p.Count() == 1
                                       && p[0].ParameterType == parameter.GetType();
                            });

                    parameters = new[]
                    {
                        parameter
                    };
                }

                if (constructor == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "No suitable constructor found for page " + pageKey);
                }

                var page = constructor.Invoke(parameters) as Page;
                _navigation.PushAsync(page, animate);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    string.Format(
                        "No such page: {0}. Did you forget to call NavigationService.Configure?",
                        pageKey),
                    "pageKey");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Configure(string pageKey, Type pageType)
    {
        lock (_pagesByKey)
        {
            if (_pagesByKey.ContainsKey(pageKey))
            {
                _pagesByKey[pageKey] = pageType;
            }
            else
            {
                _pagesByKey.Add(pageKey, pageType);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(NavigationPage navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
    }

}
```

From here, you can add other methods you would like. Make sure to inject this or use it directly where you were using your MvvmLight one before.

Comment: How to add push transition for pop ? or how to do other type of transition for example *flip*,*rotate*,*pagecurl* during push and pop process ?

Comment: Now that's a completely different question. This example is just that - an example. This uses Xamarin.Forms navigation, which doesn't include extra animations for transitions, you would have to do that custom in a `NavigationRenderer`. The point of this example is to show how you can create a custom implementation of a custom interface, and use that in-place of the MvvmLight `NavigationService`. If you want special animations, you're going to have to write that yourself or ask a separate question from this.

Comment: The custom animations for navigation has nothing to do with MvvmLight and its navigation service, but belongs to the responsibilities of the native platforms. If you want to customize that, you'll have to write some more custom code.

Comment: Are you saying we can push an pop without transition animation in MVVM and we can apply transition aimation in native platforms... I don't understand how to do that . lets take xamarin.ios as example... navigation happens in view model but how will I able to apply transition animation from native side...please explain

Comment: Please remember that stackoverflow is not a coding service. From the comments on your question, and from this example it should be doable for you to try to solve this problem for yourself now.

Comment: @FlorianMoser - I tried myself and I don't know where to proceed for the different animation part.. if I could get some clues on how to do ... it'd be really great

Comment: Xamarin has demos for iOS navigation transitions here: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/TransitionsDemo/ 

If you follow their pattern, you can use it as an implementation in your custon navigation service.